# Trying to unset an array in php but cant figure out how

Tags: php, arrays

**My Json File:**

```
"steam:1100001186575b4":[{"spawncode":"Sheepyr8tt","allowed":true},{"spawncode":"rikorwb","allowed":true},{"spawncode":"lexy","allowed":true}]
```

My goal is to send the steam and spawn code through a form and remove that spawn code from that steam.

**My PHP File:**

```
$data = file_get_contents("whitelist.json");

$array = json_decode($data, true);

if(array_key_exists($steamHex, $array)) {
    $oldData = array([
        'spawncode' => $spawncode,
        'allowed' => true
    ]);
    
    unset($array[$oldData]);
}


$myfile = fopen("whitelist.json", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, json_encode($array));
fclose($myfile);
```

At the moment it doesn't remove the spawn code from the array, I tried some other ways such as

```
unset($array[$steamHex], $oldData)
```

but it ends up removing the entire steam and all the spawncodes.

If someone has a solution please let me know!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$spawncode` is the one you want to remove:

```
$steamCode = 'steam code goes here';
$spawncode = 'spawn code to remove goes here';
$data = file_get_contents("whitelist.json");

$array = json_decode($data, true);

if (!empty($array[$steamCode])) {
    $array[$steamCode] = array_values(
        array_filter($array[$steamCode], function($scObject) use ($spawncode) {
            return $scObject['spawncode'] !== $spawncode;
        })
    );
}

$myfile = fopen("whitelist.json", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, json_encode($array));
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: That seems to have just wiped the enitre json file.

Comment: and yes I'm trying to remove the spawncode from the array, so for example if I put in "rikorwb" it should remove {"spawncode":"rikorwb","allowed":true},  from the array

Comment: It works correctly in my tests. Btw this assumes that your JSON is actually:  `{"steam:1100001186575b4":[{"spawncode":"Sheepyr8tt","allowed":true},{"spawncode":"rikorwb","allowed":true},{"spawncode":"lexy","allowed":true}]}` i.e. wrapped in `{}` as what you originally posted is invalid without this

Comment: Running this with `$spawncode` set to `Sheepyr8tt` produces `{"steam:1100001186575b4":[{"spawncode":"rikorwb","allowed":true},{"spawncode":"lexy","allowed":true}]}` - https://3v4l.org/9bLmG

Comment: Ye it is formatted like that, here is the json with a few more stuff, its really big so I cant send all of it:  {"steam:11000010f668200":[{"spawncode":"ls430","allowed":true},{"spawncode":"lexy","allowed":true}],"steam:11000010ef35135":[{"spawncode":"lexy","allowed":true},{"spawncode":"slammedf100","allowed":true},{"spawncode":"m3e36","allowed":true},{"spawncode":"f40","allowed":true}],"steam:110000114263851":[{"spawncode":"majsr","allowed":true}],"steam:1100001121769fd":[{"spawncode":"tunak","allowed":true},{"spawncode":"cp9a","allowed":true}]

Comment: This is a vardump of the array: 

array(92) { ["steam:11000010f668200"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["spawncode"]=> string(5) "ls430" ["allowed"]=> bool(true) } [1]=> array(2) { ["spawncode"]=> string(4) "lexy" ["allowed"]=> bool(true) } } ["steam:11000010ef35135"]=> array(4) { [0]=> array(2) { ["spawncode"]=> string(4) "lexy" ["allowed"]=> bool(true) } [1]=> array(2) { ["spawncode"]=> string(11) "slammedf100" ["allowed"]=> bool(true) } [2]=> array(2) { ["spawncode"]=>

Comment: Can you make sure you have the latest code I posted (I did make a quick edit so perhaps you got the previous version) and make sure you've defined `$spawncode`, once you've done that if you add `echo json_encode($array);` after the array map does that look correct?

Comment: Let me give your solution another go incase I messed up some input

Comment: Okay so it slightly works, it removes the spawncode from the array but it removes it from all the steams, I want it to just remove it from the steam I specify.

Comment: Ok I don't think you mentioned that in your original question. I've updated the solution to only operate on a specified steam code. EDIT: Sorry I see you did mention it